# Visual Studio 2015 Database project

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2015, database-deployment

I need to exclude some tables from publishing in a database project, the main idea is to publish only a subset of tables depending on the build configuration, if it's Debug I want to publish all the tables but if the configuration is Release I want to publish just a subset of those tables.

Comment: possible duplicate [Database project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165688/how-to-publish-visual-studio-database-project-in-vs-2015)

Comment: Found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531250/vs-2013-database-project-post-deployment-scripts-to-run-based-off-of-build-conf

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[Conditional("RELEASE")]
public static void InsertConditionally(YourDbContext context)
{
    context.Database.Migrate();

    if( !context.Products.Any())
    {
        context.Products.AddRange(
            new Product("name 1 release", "param 1"),
            new Product("name 2 release", "param 1"),
            new Product("name 3 release", "param 1")
            );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }


}


[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void InsertConditionally(YourDbContext context)
{
    context.Database.Migrate();

    if (!context.Products.Any())
    {
        context.Products.AddRange(
            new Product("name 1 debug", "param 1"),
            new Product("name 2 debug", "param 1"),
            new Product("name 3 debug", "param 1")
            );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```